# R local global variables

Tags: r, global-variables, local-variables

I am trying to update a global variable (matrix names : "confusion.mat") within a function

```
register.hit <-function(categ){
  confusion.mat[categ,categ] = confusion.mat[categ,categ] + 1
  }
sapply(intersection.list,register.hit)
```

data:

```
 confusion.mat <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
 intersection.list <- c(1, 2)
```

however, the global variable confusion.mat is not updated (in debugging mode, I noticed that the local variable confusion.mat within function register.hit is updated correctly).
Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you make a reproducable example? I can't seem to recreate the problem in `R`.

Comment: This is by design. `functions` shouldn't have side effects. Use `apply` like functions if your functions returns something. Otherwise stay with a `for` loop. Of course, there might well be a better, vectorized solution, but you don't describe what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe this is your goal? `diag(confusion.mat) <- seq_len(nrow(confusion.mat))`

Comment: I thought I did provide reproducible example (dput data)

Answer (score 0):

after extensive googling I found that the operator <<-
is assigning a global variable inside a function scope
so I changes my code accordingly :

```
register.hit <-function(categ){
  confusion.mat[categ,categ] <<- confusion.mat[categ,categ] + 1
  }
```

and it works

Comment: Do not use `<<-`. It's for experts and not for newbies that don't know the dangers of this operator. During your web search you should have seen a few warnings against using `<<-`.

Comment: I wouldn't be so cautious about `<<-`. `sapply` does not make global affectation as basic `for` because it is uses as `res <-  sapply(...`. It does not aim at updating value but make calculation and return a result instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized way to achieve the same result:

```
confusion.mat <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
confusion.mat[cbind(intersection.list, intersection.list)] <- 
  confusion.mat[cbind(intersection.list, intersection.list)] + 1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    0
```